# How can I package a native binary as a global dotnet tool

Tags: .net-core-2.1

I have rust binaries that I want to package as global dotnet tools. I cant find anything in the documentation on how one might do this.

I checked some of the existing tools' .nupkg files and have a few questions

1. Under the `tools` folder is a folder called `dotnetcoreapp2.1`. Can I keep the folder name even if my app is not dotnet core?
2. What does the `dotnetcoreapp2.1/any` folder mean?
3. In `DotnetToolSettings.xml`, what are the valid values for the `Runner` attribute? All the examples I saw has a "dotnet" runner

Answer (score 0):

Asked this question in dotnet/cli github repo and the answer is: NO, its not supported (yet).

see: https://github.com/dotnet/cli/issues/9488#issuecomment-397166215

> *Under the tools folder is a folder called dotnetcoreapp2.1. Can I keep the folder name even if my app is not dotnet core?*
>
> **This is TFM your tool is targeting. So under our current model, IF binary is supported, it should be any.**
>
> *What does the dotnetcoreapp2.1/any folder mean?*
>
> **It is TFM/RID. Currently only any (has to be OS agnostic) is supported, so this field need to be any.**
>
> *In DotnetToolSettings.xml, what are the valid values for the Runner attribute? All the examples I saw has a "dotnet" runner*
>
> **Only dotnet is valid runner today. We do plan to expend it. So the field is left for future.**